# Can I lie to prevent an argument?

Tags: halal-haram, lying

So my friend called me yesterday but I didn’t feel like talking. She got mad this morning and I told her I was sleeping and didn’t see her call and she said that she saw me online on Facebook.
Can I lie and say I probably forgot my Facebook open on my laptop?

Comment: Is there a problem in just telling the truth the you didn't feel like talking to people at the time?

Comment: Yes she will get offended

Comment: You started with a lie and hence you are in this situation

Answer (score -2):

It is kinda OK to lie in such situations. I do it often when I have such situations. Last night, mine colleague asked me to go for Pizza (she is married) but I said I have to sleep early today as I feel much sleepy, she understood I just don't want to go with non-muharram. Few weeks ago another girl (from one of the arab countries) asked me if we could go for coffee, I said may be next weekend, then again next weekend, then again next weekend, finally I said I am much busy these days with my work, we shall see it in future. Your case is kinda similar, it is good to avoid arguments by making excuses because argument deadens the heart and makes our hearts ugly and dark. It kills the relationships. It is not a lie actually but an excuse to avoid something which is harmful to both of you. Allah knows your intention. Peace!